# Storing a value in a register and when is it address and when pure value

Tags: assembly

Let's take this code:

```
mov eax, [esp] ; value of what inside esp
add esp, 4     ; memory or effective address
```

As you can, by default -- without [] -- we work with memory in Assembly. However, why if I want to store 123 in a register, I don't have to use []?

```
mov eax, 123   ; is 123 a memory address? or pure value?
```

Hence, how is 123 treated here: as a value or address? It's a value, but why not address? Based on the previous example, it must be an address. Or does it depend on a register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mov eax,[esp]`

Does not move the contents of `esp` into eax.
Instead it interprets the number stored into esp as an address and uses that address to get the contents of memory; then it returns whatever is stored at that memory address.

Graphically:

```
esp [0x760001]

memory
          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ......
 760000   AA  BB  CC  DD  FF  FF  FF  FF .....
 770000   11  22  33  44  .......
 780000   ................
```

At memory addresses `0x760001` to `0x760004` we've stored the value `DDCCBBAA` (4 bytes).
At memory address `0x760005` to `0x760008` we've stored the value `FFFFFFFF` (4 bytes).

Whenever we use `[...]` we are talking about pointers. A pointer is a number that denotes a location (aka address) in memory.
If we perform `mov eax,[esp]` we don't care about the numeric value of esp, but about the memory esp is pointing to.
If we perform `mov eax,esp` we are loading the literal value inside `esp` into `eax`.

If we do `mov eax,123` we just fill `eax` with the literal number 123.

The CPU does not care much whether the number in a register is a literal number or an address. It will happily perform calculations with either, after all an address is just another number.

However when we use the `[q]` we are telling the CPU to go look up the contains of memory at location `[q]`.
If we don't use `[]` we are simply using the number stored in the register as is.
We may later use this number again as a pointer.

**One exception**
The **only** exception is the `lea` instruction (e.g. `lea eax,[eax+4]`: eax = eax + 4). That instruction does not look up anything in memory, it performs calculations with numbers (which may or may not be addresses).

> Does it depend on a register?

No, all registers can be used as dual purpose registers (both for calculations and as pointers).
The only exception is `esp` which points to the stack. The cpu allows you to do calculations with it, but your program will crash if it does not contain a valid address when an interrupt occurs.

> However, why if I want to store 123 in a register, I don't have to use []?

No, because the value `123` will be encoded into the instruction itself. The cpu does not have to go out to memory to retrieve the `123` value. It is already loaded into the cpu when the instruction is fetched.

> Based on the previous example, it must be an address.

It can be an address, because an address is just a number.
Hardcoding addresses is unlikely however. In modern programs all addresses are relative because programs can be moved around in memory.

Comment: I'm confused. Then there's no such a term as "address of a register", is there?

Comment: In light of the little endianness, you should perhaps write the value as **DDCCBBAA**.

Comment: I find the lines with addresses 770000 and 780000 especially confusing! Why did you write those?

Comment: @Andy.Dok, no a register does not have an address. This is because it's located in the CPU, not in memory. Only memory needs addresses.