# Direct memory addressing in Assembly and []

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

I'm reading this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-purpose_registers_.2864-bit_naming_conventions.29

At **Direct memory addressing** it says:

```
.data
  my_var dw 0abcdh ; my_var = 0xabcd

.code
  mov ax, [my_var] ; copy my_var content into ax (ax=0xabcd)
```

I wonder, what would it copy to ax without [] if not its value which is 0xabcd?

And why is it the content in the first place? Shouldn't it treat **0xabcd** as a memory address and go look what's stored at the address **0xabcd** instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`my_var` is a *symbol* referring to some memory address. The directive

```
my_var dw 0abcdh
```

causes the assembler to allocate two bytes of storage, write the value `0abcdh` to it and then let `my_var` point to the beginning of that storage.

The comment `my_var = 0xabcd` wants to explain that the variable `my_var` points to has this value. To understand this, observe that in high-level languages like C, when you declare a global variable, the variable name is always implicitly dereferenced:

```
int foo = 1;
// compiles to
foo dw 1
```

> I wonder, what would it copy to ax without [] if not its value which is 0xabcd?

If you do not use a memory reference, the value of the symbol `my_var`, i.e. the address of that variable, is copied.  For example,

```
    mov ax, my_var
```

is as if you wrote

```
    ax = &my_var;
```

in C.

> And why is it the content in the first place? Shouldn't it treat 0xabcd as a memory address and go look what's stored at the address 0xabcd instead?

No. To do that, you need two memory accesses as you first need to fetch the content of `my_var` to get `0xabcd` and then fetch from `0xabcd` to get what is there:

```
mov bx,[myvar]
mov ax,[bx]
```

Comment: `If you do not use a memory reference, the value of the symbol my_var, i.e. the address of that variable, is copied. ` -- does this mean that in assembly, unlike in HLL, a variable is a pointer by default?

Comment: also, `mov bx,[myvar]` fetches the content of my_var, right? but that goes against this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050480/storing-a-value-in-a-register-and-when-is-it-address-and-when-pure-value/42050785#42050785 --- **....Does not move the contents of esp into eax.**

Comment: @Kotaa A (static) variable is a piece of memory. Symbols refer to addresses, so the symbol for a variable always refers to the address of that variable. You cannot change the value of a symbol at runtime as symbols are resolved before the program starts. To your link: Note that `esp` is a register, not a symbol. Registers can contain values and these values can change. The explanation is entirely correct.

Comment: @Kotaa Your confusion probably comes from the two different uses of the word “contains.” A variable *contains* a value that is stored in it. To access this value, you use the variable's symbol to get the variable's address and then load from it. A register *contains* a value. To access this value, you use `mov` to copy it from the register to some other place. No load from memory (and thus no brackets) is needed since the value is already in a register.

Comment: `If you do not use a memory reference, the value of the symbol my_var, i.e. the address of that variable, is copied`. -- does this mean that in assembly, unlike in HLL, a variable is a pointer by default?

Comment: I think not, though.

Comment: Ah, in case of variable we'd need "mov eax, [[var1]]" right? if the operator [[ ]] existed. that is, to do the same thing as "mov eax, [r9]" for example.

Comment: I would actually refrain from thinking about "variables" in assembly, especially with NASM, as symbols are bookmarks into memory, unaware whether you wrote after `my_var:` some `dw` or `dd`, or even some instruction. Also I advise to use colon `:` after every label, even the ones belonging to "variables". Registers are special pieces memory directly on the CPU chip, not in the external RAM chip, so they are quick to access and have fixed "address" by their register name, that's why the `[]` difference exists, to see immediately when CPU has to fetch value from external chip.

Comment: `Also I advise to use colon : after every label, even the ones belonging to "variables". ` - why?

Answer (score 1):

Kotaa

Basically:

```
mov  ax, my_var   ; Moves the location of my_var into ax
mov  ax, [my_var] ; Moves the content found at the address of my_var
```

To your second block of questions. If, indeed, `my_var` was supposed to hold a pointer to another block of data then:

```
mov  eax, [my_var]  ; Get pointer stored at my_var
mov  ebx, [eax]      ; Get data from pointer whose address is in eax
```

Comment: Note that `mov bx,[ax]` is not a valid addressing mode.

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050480/storing-a-value-in-a-register-and-when-is-it-address-and-when-pure-value/42050785#42050785 --- **mov eax,[esp] ===>

Does not move the contents of esp into eax.**

Comment: @Kotaa - It's kind of confusing at first, but just depends on the convention the designer selected. `mov eax,esp` cannot mean "get the address of esp", because esp doesn't have an address. So it was made to mean "get the value from esp". That's it.